# Constrained optimization between two bayesian variables

Tags: optimization, reinforcement-learning, bayesian-network, bayesian-optimization, constrained-optimization

I have 2 separate Bayesain networks and I was hoping to maximize `Value` within the constraint of the `Cost`. What are is a good way I can do that?

Some notes about the model:

1. Cost is observed per unit, but there is a global constraint on Cost.
2. Value is not observed, so latent.
3. Function between Cost and Value does not exist.

[image]